# MYSQL query optimization joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

Need help to optimize this query

The task is to select my friends from `friends` table, to check if any of them is in ignore table, to get their info from users table, also to get the last message date from messages table. My friends also can be group's.

My query:

```
SELECT
        `u`.`id`, `u`.`login`, `u`.`name`, `u`.`surname`,
        CONCAT(`u`.`name`, ' ', `u`.`surname`) AS `namesurname`, `u`.`avatar`,
        `u`.`status`, `u`.`status_text`, `u`.`last_active`, `u`.`type`,
        `f`.`status` AS `friend_state`, `i`.`date` AS `ignore_date`,
        MAX(`m`.`date`) AS `last_message_date` 
    FROM `friends` AS f 
    INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON `u`.`id`=`f`.`friend_id`
    LEFT JOIN `ignore` AS `i` ON `i`.`uid`='10' AND `i`.`ignore_id`=`f`.`friend_id`
    LEFT JOIN `messages` AS `m` ON `m`.`date`>DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND 
    (
        (`m`.`fromid`=`u`.`id` AND `m`.`toid`='10') OR 
        (`m`.`toid`=`u`.`id` AND `m`.`fromid`='10') OR
        (`m`.`toid`=`u`.`id` AND `m`.`toid` IN (16,22,27))
    ) 
    WHERE `f`.`uid`='10'
    GROUP BY `u`.`id`
    ORDER BY `last_message_date` DESC, `namesurname`
```

For 170k messages this query tooks 2.2-2.5 seconds.

if I remove

```
(`m`.`toid`=`u`.`id` AND `m`.`toid` IN (16,22,27))
```

the it tooks 0.55 seconds

10 - is my users ID

16,22,27 - id of groups

I need this line (`m`.`toid`=`u`.`id` AND `m`.`toid` IN (16,22,27)) because in group chats it shouldn't depend on who sent the last message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those backticks.... yuck.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your tables? Please add the execution plan (the output of `explain select ...`). Also, does your additional condition change the number of considered rows? E.g., how many rows do you get (without the `group by`) with or without that additional term?

Comment: actually, `m.toid=u.id AND m.toid IN (16,22,27))` should better be `m.toid IN (16,22,27))` since checking both, _u.id_ and _m.toid_ doesn't make any sense if _m.toid_ later must be one of the given three values. if there's not auto-optimization by MySQL itself, it first checks all _m.toid_ on _u.id_ and then the three values, whereas only checking the `IN (...)` is needed

Comment: @meistermuh removing m.toid=u.id didn't make any sense. also because it is in ON conditions, if i remove m.toid=u.id then the last message date will be from any of the groups, but i need it from relevant groups messages.

Comment: @solarflare yes i have indexes on tables

here is explain for this query
https://ibb.co/ZH0VdST

without group by i get more rows, without this condition i didn't get last message time from group if i haven't sent any messages to this group in last 1 day

Comment: Sorry, here is explain for this query,
https://ibb.co/2NVbVvh

Comment: problem solved. added index to date column of messages table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need `LEFT`.  Assuming that, I would turn the `ORs` into `UNIONs` and *start* with such:

Since you have not provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I will guess that `messages` has `PRIMARY KEY(mid)`.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( ( SELECT mid FROM messages WHERE fromid = u.id AND toid = 10 )
           UNION ALL 
           ( SELECT mid FROM messages WHERE toid = u.id AND fromid = 10 )
           UNION ALL 
           ( SELECT mid FROM messages WHERE toid = u.id AND toid IN (16,22,27) ) AS um
    JOIN users AS u  ON ...
    JOIN
```

Oops, instead I will approach it from trying to do as much as possible in `messages` first, assuming the 1-day limitation is a significant filter.  (Notice how an estimated 170K rows need to be scanned.)

Start by checking this to see if it is 'fast' and delivers not 'too many' rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        ( SELECT toid AS either_id, MAX(date) AS last_date FROM messages
             WHERE toid IN (10, 16,22,27) AND date > NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
        UNION ALL   -- or, if you get dups, UNION ALL
        ( SELECT fromid, MAX(date) FROM messages
             WHERE fromid = 10 AND date > NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
                     ) um;
```

Assuming that is OK, then work on

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( ... ) AS um   -- the derived table above
    JOIN users AS u  ON um.either_id = u.id
    JOIN ...   -- the rest of the stuff
```

Indexes...

```
messages:  (toid, date)
messages:  (fromid, date)
```

(It's a really messy query, so I don't have confidence that I have helped.)

Comment: Thank you @Rick James for the time you spent for me. The problem was solved after adding index to date column of messages table, now that query's time is about 0.0056